# Advanced ordering of query_posts

Tags: wp-query, order

I'm working on a rather large and old Wordpress project where someone has previously used `query_posts` all over the place. For this reason, I'm unwilling to change those method calls. I'm not the maintainer of the site, I'm doing a quick fix.

Each post in question has a field called `our_date`, which represents a  date and a time, and `title`. The customer wants the posts ordered by `title`, but so that the *future* posts appear first in the list and all the past dates at the bottom.

This is what I'm working with right now:

```
'orderby' => array('date' => 'ASC'),
```

What's the best way to accomplish this custom sorting of results from `query_posts`?

Comment: So two lists of posts?  Those yet to be be published, sorted by title, followed by those already published, sorted by title?   If so, that's cake and pie.  Regardless of whether the site uses `query_posts` in other places, what prevents you from using `WP_Query` class here on this page?

Comment: "Future" ? It's not default for WP to even query future posts on front end. For starters how is that implemented and what full queries look like? Do you mean that date should be from custom field, not actual post date? Is title native or custom field as well?

Comment: @Rarst: I didn't know that, it explains a lot I guess. `our_date` is a custom field, but `title` is the native field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is doable in a single WP API query. You just don't sort whole set with single logic, you have logic *changing* halfway. I don't think even SQL can express this.

It is hard to advise without seeing specific circumstances (such as counts, pagination involved and so on), but my first thought would be to split this into two queries:

1. "Future" posts (meta query for date field in future, order by title)
2. "Past" posts (meta query for date field in the past, order by title)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, wordpress queries do not have the ability to sort by two keys. I am far from being a mysql person, but I am sure that you can write such a query, which means that you can use the relevant query related filters to adjust the sql query generated by wordpress to be the desired one.

But I would probably just switch the use of query_posts to proper use of `wp_query`, and sort the resulting posts in PHP. The performance hit should be negligible (virtually zero if page caching is used) and the code a little more straight forward.